# Extracting Wordpress.zip file on Linux server

Tags: zip, mv, wordpress

I'm new to `Linux` and I'm currently trying to do the following:

- unzip the contents of wordpress-4.1.1.zip to the directory in which it is contained which is /my-test-site/wordpress-4.1.1.zip

I understand to `unzip` I can run this command from within the directory:

`unzip wordpress-4.1.1.zip`

but that then leaves me with a sub directory called wordpress. I can then go in and run this command from the sub directory in order to move the files up a level:

```
mv * ../
```

If I do that I then have all of the wordpress core files in the my-test-site directory which I want. But I'm wondering If I can run the unzip command in such a way that it extracts the contents directly into my-test-site directory and doesnt  create a sub directory containing the files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two command line options to `unzip` to get your desired result, **provided the zip contains no sub directories**.

```
unzip -j -d /my-test-site wordpress-4.1.1.zip
```

Note that if your zip was of the order:

```
foo
├── 1
├── 2
├── 3
├── 4
├── 5
├── 6
├── 7
├── 8
├── 9
└── bar
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    ├── 3
    ├── 4
    ├── 5
    ├── 6
    ├── 7
    ├── 8
    └── 9
```

Using this option would mean the files contained in `foo/bar` would clobber (replace the contents of) all files located in `foo`. I.e, the `-j` option removes *all* paths relatives to the file locations in the zip and puts in them in either the current directory (default) or the directory specified by the `-d` option.

If your zip has sub-directories, your method would be the way to go about extracting that zip file.

You could always alias the command:

```
alias wp_unzip='mv wordpress-4.1.1.zip /my-test-site && \
    cd /my-test-site && unzip wordpress-4.1.1.zip && \
    mv wordpress/* . && rmdir wordpress'
```

Comment: Yes you see my issue is that the zip file has a number of sub directories so I guess I'll have to go about it the initial way. Thank you for your helpful answer. It's good to know that this is possible.